# Versioned model

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I am thinking of how best to implement a model that cannot be modified (ie: each time the model data is modified, a new instance of the object is created and a reference is added to the previous instance to reflect the fact that the old object has been deprecated by the new one).

At the moment something quick and dirty that I thought up looks something like this:

```
class VersionedModel(models.Model):
    # points to initial reference
    initial = models.ForeignKey(VersionedModel, verbose_name=_(u"initial"), related_name="versions", editable=False)
    # ought to be a one-one reference
    deprecated_by = models.ForeignKey(VersionedModel, ...)
    version = models.IntegerField(...)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self):
        prev_pk = self.pk
        self.pk = None
        prev = self.objects.get(pk=prev_pk)
        prev.deprecated_by = self
        super(self.__class__), self).save()
```

Something tells me that even if this does works it is probably a very lousy way to do it. Is there a more "elegant" solution to do such a thing?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are changing an objects pk you will eg run into problems if you have relations pointing to it....

Answer (score 1):

You should maybe have a look at [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion).

Comment: Very difficult when removed or added a new field =(